# merge dataframe columns into a nested key with dynamic column names or with index

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dynamic-columns

I am new to python and pandas. I need to merge multiple columns on a dataframe into a nested key in the output json. The column names are dynamic except name column.

input:

```
   name      384925  504100  296371  487730  296373  487729  296374  489406  296400  486601  384113
0  abc       0.0     0.0    -0.375   0.0     0.375   0.000   0.5     0.00    0.5     0.000   0.5
1  def       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2  xyz       0.0     0.0    -0.375   0.0     0.375   0.000   0.5     0.00    0.5     0.000   0.5
```

The expected output json

```
[
 {
   "name": "abc",
   "sizes": [
    { "384925": 0.0 },
      { "504100": 0.0 },
      { "296371": -0.375 },
      { "487730": 0.0 },
      { "296373": 0.375 },
      { "487729": 0.0 },
      { "296374": 0.5 },
      { "489406": 0.0 },
      { "296400": 0.5 },
      { "486601": 0.0 },
      { "384113": 0.5 }
   ]
 },
{
   "name": "def",
   "sizes": [
    { "384925": null },
      { "504100": null },
      { "296371": null },
      ...
      { "486601": null },
      { "384113": null }
   ]
 },
{
   "name": "xyz",
   "sizes": [
    { "384925": 0.0 },
      { "504100": 0.0 },
      { "296371": -0.375 },
      ...
      { "486601": 0.0 },
      { "384113": 0.5 }
   ]
 },
]
```

code I tried

```
df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x: tuple(x)).to_dict()

json_out = df.to_json(orient='records')
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner, to create the desired output

```
out = [
    {'name': gname, 'sizes': gdf.drop(columns='name').to_dict(orient='records')}
    for gname, gdf in df.groupby('name')
]
```

If you wanna convert to json,

```
json.dumps(out)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This gives the sizes as array. Is there a way to add dict to each row in the sizes
```
[{    "name": "abc"
    "sizes": [
      {
        "384925": 0.0,
        "504100": 0.0,
        "296371": -0.375,
        "487730": 0.0,
        "296373": 0.375,
        "487729": 0.0,
        "296374": 0.5,
        "489406": 0.0,
        "296400": 0.5,
        "486601": 0.0,
        "384113": 0.5
      }
    ]
}, {..}, {..}]
```

Comment: Sizes is an array/list of dicts.

Comment: What happens if `abc` has multiple rows?

Comment: i mean the sizes to be list of objects
"sizes": [
      { "384925": 0.0 },
      { "504100": 0.0 },
      { "296371": -0.375 } .. ]

Comment: You won't be able to factor in multiple rows in this case

Comment: transpose did the magic. However, the output had the "index" key in it.
out = [
    {'name': gname, 'sizes': gdf.drop(columns='name').T.reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')}
    for gname, gdf in df.groupby('name')
]

Comment: Use `reset_index(drop=True)` for having no index @rigisa